# How can I make this more readable? I need to change the space around the words, but do not know how big to make it

Tags: typography, layout

I've got a big strategic road map that I created in Visio. I know that Visio is not the ideal choice for all elements of this project, but it checked most of the boxes without having much downside. However, one downside is that subtle changes are time-consuming because everything needs to be manually adjusted.

So I have created this thing and I have feedback that it's hard to read. Feedback is also that opening up the space around the text fixes it. So I want to add space, but not too much, because economy of spacing is important.

[image]

Are there guidelines for spacing things like this? Ratios or something?

Rather than just guess, I prefer some sort of guide if one exists. A rule of thumb or something?

Should I maybe also increase the vertical spacing between elements?

[image]

Comment: Does "Define Organization" actually take place in May? If not, stacking to 2 lines and remaining within the active months is preferred - otherwise it's unclear and confusing. And yes, more vertical padding would increase readability.

Comment: I’ve got a key at the top that explains that the dark border indicates the scheduled duration. In our organization, the start dates are the most important data point. And we’ve got some long Activity names that take place inside a month.

Comment: Again, stacking and constraining to active months would improve clarity. If you *don't actually want advice*. That's fine.

Comment: @Scott I will test some things out. I hope to find some ratios, or some other guidance, about how much padding and margin is ideal. The feedback was not that the durations are hard to understand, but that the text is hard to read.

Comment: If the name and start date are the important aspects.. I'd probably eliminate the *entire* "boxy" aspect. It's all speculation and *opinion based* though. And without a full understanding of everything entailed it's pretty difficult to be definitive. Legibility is increased by spacing, size, and contrast. If all you care about is legibility then address those.